# asp.net web api, Combine EntityFramework generated models with ApplicationUser model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Hi im a beginner in the use of asp.net framework and web development.
So im leaerning by starting a project.
Im using `asp.net web api`. Im having issues understanding how to use my
own entity framework codefirst database generated models, with the `AppUserModel`  found in the 
IdentityModel.cs.
The thing is that i have a class library where i defined a model
 Staff. It contains properties like `ID` `Username`, `password`, `Name`,
and `StaffCategory`. For the `staffCategory` this is defined in another
file as an `enum`. Where the keys are `Employee` and `Manager`.
THis model is mapped to my existing database.
From the way i designed this model, i had intended to use it as my user account.
Also then in my code i intended to add roles `EmployeeRole` and `ManagerRole` corresponsng to `StaffCategory`.
But now on creating the `asp.net web application` i see that there is a user model already.
`ApplicationUser`. And is used for user account creation and authentication.
Im really confused now about how my model `Staff` fits in right now.
My questions are
1. Can i use my own model(`Staff`) for user account? If so is it best practice,
and how can i achieve this? And how do i mix roles with it?
2.If i cannot use my `Staff` model for user accounts. How do i use the `ApplicationUser` Model
together with my `Staff` model?

Sorry if my question is bulky. But i have pondered and researched for so long without staright answers to
these questions. So i just need to find out.
Ohh and example code for this would be really helpful for better understanding.
Thanks in advance.